# Blobstore/FileService writes suddenly failing 100% of the time

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

It's worked fine for weeks and was working fine at noon today and then (without any deployment/changes) it suddenly started failing 100% of the time. It's failing in production for the same URLs that worked yesterday and that still work fine in development.

I image it's a service-outage of some kind but the App Engine status page shows all green.

Here's the stack trace:

```
java.io.IOException
at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.translateException(FileServiceImpl.java:588)
at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.makeSyncCall(FileServiceImpl.java:561)
at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.create(FileServiceImpl.java:479)
at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.createNewBlobFile(FileServiceImpl.java:99)
at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.createNewBlobFile(FileServiceImpl.java:81)
at mikelike.common.Image.getImageFromUrl(Image.java:303)
at mikelike.account.PinFactory.createPin(PinFactory.java:251)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.ml.account.add_jsp._jspService(add_jsp.java:123)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
at mikelike.common.HideJspServlet.doGet(HideJspServlet.java:24)
at mikelike.common.HideJspServlet.doPost(HideJspServlet.java:31)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at mikelike.common.MikeLikeServletFilter.doFilter(MikeLikeServletFilter.java:190)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:102)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:249)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:422)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 1:
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1495)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.doSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:235)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.access$000(ApiProxyImpl.java:68)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:180)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:178)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:178)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:68)
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:101)
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:50)
at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.makeSyncCall(FileServiceImpl.java:557)
... 52 more
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 1:
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.failure(ApiProxyImpl.java:544)
at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher$1.runInContext(RpcStub.java:748)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.rpcFinished(RpcStub.java:788)
at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.failure(RpcStub.java:779)
at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.runCallbacks(RpcClientInternalContext.java:890)
at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.finishRpcAndNotifyApp(RpcClientInternalContext.java:793)
at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.afterFinishingActiveRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1049)
at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.finishRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:895)
at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.handleResponse(RpcNetChannel.java:2248)
at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.messageReceived(RpcNetChannel.java:2060)
at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.access$2000(RpcNetChannel.java:147)
at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcNetChannel.java:3097)
at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcChannelTransportData$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcChannelTransportData.java:602)
at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcBaseTransport.receivedMessage(RpcBaseTransport.java:420)
at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport.parseOneMessage(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:773)
at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport.parseMessages(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:651)
at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport.access$100(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:38)
at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport$1.dataReceived(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:293)
at com.google.net.async3.SocketConnection.handleNetworkReadEvent(SocketConnection.java:843)
at com.google.net.async3.SocketConnection.access$400(SocketConnection.java:40)
at com.google.net.async3.SocketConnection$NetworkReadHandlerImpl.run(SocketConnection.java:872)
at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask$Sync.innerRun(AbstractFutureTask.java:260)
at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask.run(AbstractFutureTask.java:121)
at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runTask(EventManagerImpl.java:576)
at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.internalRunWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:997)
at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:878)
at com.google.net.eventmanager.WorkerThreadInfo.runWorkerLoop(WorkerThreadInfo.java:134)
at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl$WorkerThread.run(EventManagerImpl.java:1833)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for debugging, or for getting Google engineering eyes on it?  Is anyone else experiencing this?

Here's my code, in case it helps put things in context.

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
conn.setReadTimeout(15000);

String contentType = conn.getContentType();

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile(contentType);
FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, true);

int nRead;
byte[] data = new byte[8192];
while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
    writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(data,0,nRead));
}

writeChannel.closeFinally();
BlobKey blobKey = fileService.getBlobKey(file);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered your post on the appengine forum - essentially the files API is currently experimental. While efforts are underway to improve it's reliability so that it can move out of experimental status you should be careful about using it in a mission critical code path.

I have observed that a lot of the time it fails with DeadlineExceeded errors - perhaps you can author your code to retry the operation when this happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm sure I knew it was experimental at one point, but forgot about it.  It's been 95% reliable and then started failing 100% of the time.  My work-around is to store the images in the datastore instead of the blobstore for now.

Comment: One more thing for you - I noticed your app is using master/slave datastore. The files API writes to your datastore and you'll notice that service is more reliable if you switch your app to HRD datastore.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `IOException`  at `mikelike.common.Image.getImageFromUrl(Image.java:303)`

Before calling `conn.getInputStream()` you should check if HTTP connection was successful via [`conn.getResponseCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode%28%29).

Make sure the URL returns the data you are expecting - you should test this not only in browser but also in command line (via `wget` or `curl`).

Comment: Good advice about checking the response code of course, but the problem is not the contents of the response but the inability to write them to the blobstore.  The IO exception is from trying to open a Blob file, not from reading the URL.